# Debugging Angularjs databindings

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, mvvm

Love Angular, and love MV-* in general.  However, on any framework I've ever used, debugging databindings is just a pain -- you put the wrong binding expression in your view, and you just don't get data.  It's a big Q/A issue. for data-entry intensive applications.

Are there any resources out there for detecting/debugging databinding problems in angular?  (I'm particularly interested in detecting cases where the binding experession in the view has a typo, so that the target your binding to simply doesn't exist)

Answer (score 0):

Angular-Team develops Google-Chrome extension - [AngularJS Battarang](https://github.com/angular/angularjs-batarang)

It can extract scope, available on curent element and shows its values.